# Why isnt my controller being called from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Im trying to call a method from my erb html that will perform an action in the controller, however the action isn't being performed.

Here's the code in the html

```
<td style="text-align: center">
  <%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: "upvote(#{request.id})", class: 'upvote', id:"voteButton#{request.id}" %>
</td> </tr>
```

Here's the code in the controller

```
def upvote
  puts 'upvote'
  @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
  @request.increment!(:voteCount)
  @request.save
  render json: { voteCount: request.voteCount }
end
```

Here's the routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests do
    post 'upvote', to: 'requests#upvote'
    #get "requests/index"
  end
end
```

Theres also some JS functionality in there, but that's working fine.

Here's the JS

```
$("#ClickMe").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 



function upvote(id) {
    var count = document.getElementById("voteCount" + id).innerHTML;
    count = parseInt(count);
    count = count + 1;
    count = count.toString();
    document.getElementById("voteCount" + id).innerHTML = count;
    document.getElementById("voteButton" + id).disabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: It’s probably a good idea to add the JS in your question. Using remote true will send this as AJAX (by default, unless you have specified otherwise). Also, you have an onclick event firing, what is that doing?

Comment: I added the JS. The onclick fires the JS which increments the value on the page, but Im trying to also increment the value in the database, which is what the method in the controller is supposed to do.

Comment: OK, so it looks like you just need to set up the AJAX request/response and do some light debugging :) Here's a couple of links that may help you out.  https://medium.com/@codenode/how-to-use-remote-true-to-make-ajax-calls-in-rails-3ecbed40869b https://learnetto.com/blog/how-to-make-ajax-calls-in-rails-5-1-with-or-without-jquery

Comment: I added byebug to the controller method and it isn't being called. I think there may be something with the routes. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `onclick` supposed to do here? It's intercepting your click and (I assume) spamming errors in browser console.

Comment: Thats the part Im trying to figure out. There actually arent any errors in the console coming in, in fact, when I click the button in the browser nothing happens in the rails console or the JS console. What I want to happen is to trigger the method in my controller

Comment: @user9175041: did you write this code or did you inherit it?

Comment: im writing it myself but Im new to rails and am mostly fumbling through right now trying to figure out what's what.

Comment: ok, so I found out some new info. When I remove everything after the `onclick` in the erb, the post back happens and my db value is updated. If I leave everything as is, or if I remove everything before the `onclick`, then the JS works and the value on the page is updated. It seems that the problem is with both requests being contained in one line of code.

Comment: @user9175041: you left the `onclick` and it works? Interesting.

Comment: somewhat. The JS method that increments the count on the page works, but the class that disables the button after the click doesn't. Should it not work? I'm basically trying to perform a post and a JS function in a single click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me after lots of trial and error:

`<%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request_id: request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: "upvote(#{request.id})" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view to:

```
<td style="text-align: center"><%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request_id: request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: "upvote(#{request.id})", class: 'upvote', id:"voteButton#{request.id}" %></td> </tr>
```

Comment: didnt seem to do anything, I checked the db and the numbers are the same