# Controller to add current_user email to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column in my database that I'm trying to update in my controller. I'm trying to take the current logged in user's email and send it to the column in the model using the create method. It's not sending the email to the database though.

Here's my create method in the controller

```
def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save

        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }

        @request.email = current_user.email

        @request.increment!(:voteCount)

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm fairly certain the trouble lies in the line `@request.email = current_user.email` but Im not sure why.

The `user` model and the `request` models are different, so im trying to grab the data from one model and send it to another.

Comment: You forgot to save the record after you set the email.

Comment: so, if I add `@request.save` to the method, it should work?

Comment: Yes, provided that the column is there and there are no other hidden problems

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - Would you be able to help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54858892/why-isnt-my-controller-being-called-from-the-view) other issue I'm having? I've been stuck on it for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergio's comment helped me figure this out.

Added `@request.save`